# Shell: Copy Certain Types of Files Keeping Directory Structure

Tags: linux, shell

Say I have a folder following the structure below:

```
$ ls /tmp/level1
level2_folder1    level2_folder2
$ ls /tmp/level1/level2_folder1
input output script.py ...
$ ls /tmp/level1/level2_folder2
input output script.py ...
```

I want to copy all the ***Python scripts ONLY*** to somewhere else but keeping the existing structure. Let's say I want to copy the level1 folder to home/ so it should looks like this:

```
$ ls /home/level1
level2_folder1    level2_folder2
$ ls /home/level1/level2_folder1
script.py 
$ ls /home/level1/level2_folder2
script.py
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rsync -avz --include "*/" --include "*.py" --exclude "*" /tmp/level1 /home
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /tmp && find level1 -name '*.py' -print0 | cpio -pd0 /home
```